# Django database query round trips

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have the query below, as you can see in my loop I add each message. I want to reduce the total round trips I have to make to the DB. Is this a way I can process the message create in batches of say 20 at a time? Will this help with speed? any suggestions welcome.

```
class ProcessRequests(Task):
    """
    Celery Task to start request to process that are not scheduled.
    """
    name = "Request to Process"
    max_retries = 1
    default_retry_delay = 3

    def run(self, batch):
        # Only run this task on non-scheduled tasks
        if batch.status != "Scheduled":
            q = Contact.objects.filter(contact_owner=batch.user, subscribed=True)
            if batch.group == None:
                q = q.filter(id=batch.contact_id)
            else:
                q = q.filter(group=batch.group)

            for e in q:
                msg = Message.objects.create(
                    recipient_number=e.mobile,
                    content=batch.content,
                    sender=e.contact_owner,
                    billee=batch.user,
                    sender_name=batch.sender_name
                )
                gateway = Gateway.objects.get(pk=2)
                msg.send(gateway)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`bulk_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create).

Also note you're getting the same `gateway` object each time through the loop, it would be better to get it once outside of the loop and use the same one each time.